# A skillful person who is very familiar with "their own" profession

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, word-request, idioms

I have found a term which can be used to describe a person who knows a lot about a specific field. Imagine a carpenter or a mechanic or an electrician etc. who know a lot about their specialties and are very familiar with their own profession. How would one indicate such an ability in natural English?

This is what I found:

> - He is very [well versed](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/well-versed) in this / his business

I would relly appreciate it if someone could let me know whether there is a better term or idiom to explain such a person or not.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest saying the person was an [Expert](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/expert)

> A person who is very knowledgeable about or skilful in a particular area:

Answer (score 1):

Casual/informal:

> He's a true pro.
>
> He's an ace electrician.
>
> He's top notch in his field.

Normal register:

He's an authority on {some specialized subject}. (e.g. elastomers, equine diseases,  paleobotany).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest [connoisseur](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/connoisseur).

> He is a businesses connoisseur.

It's synonym [cognoscente](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cognoscente) is equally eloquent but sounds grandiloquous.

Also [aficionado](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aficionado).

> He is an aficionado of business.

I'm more inclined to use 'connoisseur' in this case, though.

Comment: Neither of these terms  has the shade of meaning the OP asks for.

Comment: @verbose16 Can you please clarify to me why my answer is not applicable?

Comment: Not at all @Nikki. May I ask your nationality please? :)

Comment: I am from India and not really 'well-versed' in English. Still a learner.

Comment: Actually, *connoisseur* does apply in a sense, but not to the specific examples provided in the question (carpenter, mechanic, electrician).  A *connoisseur* knows nearly all there is to know about things that have been produced by *others* (e.g. wine, food, art) whereas the question asks about people who truly know how to *do* something themselves.

Comment: Thank you very much @Nikki. I wish you all the success in this way. :)

Comment: @Nikki TRomano has explained why *connoisseur* does not apply. His comment is equally applicable to *cognoscente*. As for *aficionado*, it refers to a passionate and knowledgeable fan, not to a professional.   There are other issues with your answer. For example, it has *It's* where standard usage would dictate "Its"; the word *eloquent* doesn't fit the context; "businesses connoisseur" is odd, because a connoisseur is a specialist in a specific field, not a vast and vague one like "businesses".

Comment: @TRomano According to the dictionaries 'connoisseur', 'expert' and 'pro' are synonymous, but I take your point. Connoisseur does have a sense of wide-range-expertise to it. So to be more precise and informal, will [crackerjack](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/crackerjack) work in this case? As in 'a crackerjack mechanic'?

Comment: Yes, a "crackerjack" is very good at their job:  a crackerjack pilot | lawyer | salesman | reporter | programmer.   etc

Comment: @TRomano Thanks for you informative help. Should I modify my answer with only 'crackerjack' or should I let 'connoisseur' be a part of it so that somebody else can also know why it isn't 'the word' for this case. Or should I do nothing.